# Does $\mathbb P [ Y = 1 | X = x] \ge 1/2 \iff f_{X|Y} (x,1) \ge f_{X|Y} (x,-1)$ hold?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, density-function

Let

- $X,Y$ be random variables such that take values in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\{-1,1\}$ respectively.
- $f_{X|Y}$ be the conditional probability density function.
- $x \in \operatorname{supp}(X)$.

---

I'm trying to show the equivalence of Bayes optimal classifier [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Bayes_classifier#/Proof_of_Optimality) in the case we use $f_{X|Y}$ rather than
$\mathbb P [ Y = 1 | X = x]$. As such, I would like to ask if the following holds

$$\mathbb P [ Y = 1 | X = x] \ge 1/2 \iff f_{X|Y} (x,1) \ge f_{X|Y} (x,-1)$$

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $0<\mathbb P(Y=1)<1/2$.

Then $f_{X\mid Y}(x,1)=f_{X\mid Y}(x,-1)$.
But $\mathbb P(Y=1\mid X=x) = \mathbb P(Y=1)<1/2$.

Comment: With a stronger assumption that $\mathbb P \{X|Y=1\} \sim \mathcal N(\mu_1, \sum)$ and $\mathbb P \{X|Y=-1\} \sim \mathcal N(\mu_2, \sum)$, is it possible for that equality to hold?

Comment: You could post that as another question :)

Comment: Thank you so much!